# Mount NFS share on notebook (wlan)

Tags: systemd, nfs, fstab

I'm mounting my NAS/NFS share to /mnt/nas on my notebook/wlan connection. This did work until last week. Mounting the NFS share with two other wired PCs (same distro) still works.

In Debian / Arch Linux forums they suggested to add more `x-systemd` options to the fstab

- noauto
- x-systemd.automount
- x-systemd.requires=network-online.target
- x-systemd.device-timeout=10

My current fstab looks like this

```
192.168.220.100:/foo/bar /mnt/nas nfs  nfsvers=3,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,noauto,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,x-systemd.device-timeout=60             0 0
```

I've tried the following options in fstab `x-systemd.requires=` `network-online.target` or `systemd-networkd-wait-online.service` or `nfs-client.target` none of them worked.

`journalctl` error: mount[841]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable

When I run a `sudo mount /mnt/nas` manually after boot, it mounts the share.

How can I have my NFS share mounted automatically after boot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read this, you might probably have the same problem I had.

My hint was comming from `journalctl | grep nas`

```
systemd[1]: mnt-nas.automount: Got automount request for /mnt/nas, triggered by 746 (zeitgeist-datah)
```

I simply uninstalled the zeitgeist package - not sure why it was installed, and mounting works again